# C++/CLI 'ToInt32': is not a member of 'System::UInt32'

Tags: c++-cli, managed

As the title says i am getting this error when trying to do the following...

```
DWORD nWritten = 0;
::WriteProcessMemory(GetCurrentProcess(), hookTarget, hookBytes, HLength, &nWritten);
Console::WriteLine(nWritten.ToInt32);
```

Comment: Your question is specific to C++/CLI and has nothing to do with C++. Please tag your posts appropriately.

Comment: Also don't forget to check the return code from `::WriteProcessMemory`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to cast the `DWORD`:

```
System::Console::WriteLine((System::Int32)nWritten);
```

Here `DWORD` is native, but you were trying to use a managed method on that, which won't work.

Answer (score 0):

Chris O's answer is correct, a direct cast is best in this case.  But I just wanted to add if you wanted to use ToInt32 for a type that you can't directly cast or any of the other conversions it's Convert::ToInt32().  Intellisense misleads you into thinking you can call MyVariable.ToInt32().